# Creating a basic click bot to export and save data

Tags: python, automation, bots

I am working on a research project that involves extracting data from a hospital clinic information system (CIS). Unfortunately, the CIS is quite old and does not avail of many data exporting functions, which renders acquisition of data very time-consuming.

My idea is to create a click bot to automate the data exporting step (confidentiality and ethical approval will be guaranteed). Essentially, it would have to perform the following steps:

- Open search window in the CIS
- enter patient ID (derived from a list, e.g. in CSV format) into search window
- identify data of interest by entering string (e.g. "cardiology report") into a search window. This causes the reports to be listed.
- click on 1st report in list
- click on "save as PDF" button, enter patient code as title of PDF, click save etc
- loop through all the relevant reports
- recognise when all reports have been saved (it would probably have to count the number of "cardiology reports" and perform the respective number of loops)
- enter next patient ID and loop through entire process

Can someone recommend Python libraries or resources (also using other languages) that could be used to create such a bot? I have found many resources for website bots, but not necessarily for applications such as mine. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Explain%20how%20you%20encountered%20the,make%20a%20good%20first%20impression.

Comment: Give autoit (autoitscript.com) a try